# Mumbai international airport arrivals

Tags: airports, mumbai

I am landing 2 days earlier than the date I have told my friends who plan on coming to pick me up. Due to personal reasons I cant tell them or let them find out I landed 2 days earlier.

Is there any way I can pretend like my flight just landed and come out of the arrivals terminal on T2 with my  baggage? I was reading about visitor entry, but as a matter of fact, you cant take in luggage with you. However, I do have a friend and she is taking a domestic flight the same morning so she would be going through the the international terminal departure. Any way possible that she could come to the arrivals with my luggage?

Comment: I can't imagine why you think you need to do this and I doubt it's possible, but even if you manage to pull it off the truth is likely to emerge later. Better and easier I suspect, just to come clean.

Comment: I suggest decline their kind offer to pick you up and say you will arrive by taxicab. Your chances of getting inside the airport without a ticket (they check) aren't particularly good.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that international arrivals in Mumbai are like they are in most countries, no, you can't do this. What you're proposing is that you come out of the secure area and meet your friends. That requires you to first get *into* the secure area, and that's only possible for passengers and employees.